# Non-linear PDE coefficients problem

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, finite-element-method

I'm trying to solve the following PDE

```
NDSolveValue[{Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]*(6*Cot[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]^2 - 2*Derivative[0, 2][\[Gamma]][u, v] + 3*Cos[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]) == 
Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]*(2*(2 + Cos[2*\[Gamma][u, v]])*Csc[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]^2 + 3*Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v] - 2*Cos[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[2, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]),\[Gamma][0, v] == 1 + Sqrt[v], \[Gamma][u, 0] == 1 + u*Sin[u]}, \[Gamma], {u, 0, 1/2}, {v, 0, 1/2}]
```

however, I get the warning

```
  `The maximum derivative order of the nonlinear PDE coefficients for the Finite Element Method is larger than 1. It may help to rewrite  the PDE in inactive form`
```

which does not make sense, since the coefficients are all of derivative order 1, not larger than it. Is Mathematica not able to get the solutions of these types of quasilinear PDEs ?

---

When written in inactive form as

```
       NDSolve[{Inactive[Plus][Inactive[Times][Inactive[Derivative][1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v], Inactive[Plus][Inactive[Times][6, Inactive[Cot][Inactive[\[Gamma]][u, v]], 
    Inactive[Power][Inactive[Derivative][0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v], 2]], Inactive[Times][-1, Inactive[Times][2, Inactive[Derivative][0, 2][\[Gamma]][u, v]]], 
   Inactive[Times][3, Inactive[Cos][Inactive[\[Gamma]][u, v]], Inactive[Derivative][1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]]]], Inactive[Times][-1, Inactive[Times][Inactive[Derivative][0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v], 
   Inactive[Plus][Inactive[Times][2, Inactive[Plus][2, Inactive[Cos][Inactive[Times][2, Inactive[\[Gamma]][u, v]]]], Inactive[Csc][Inactive[\[Gamma]][u, v]], 
     Inactive[Power][Inactive[Derivative][1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v], 2]], Inactive[Times][3, Inactive[Derivative][1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]], 
    Inactive[Times][-1, Inactive[Times][2, Inactive[Cos][Inactive[\[Gamma]][u, v]], Inactive[Derivative][2, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]]]]]]] == 0, DirichletCondition[{\[Gamma][0, v] == 1 + Sqrt[v]}, u == 0], DirichletCondition[{\[Gamma][u, 0] == 1 + u*Sin[u]}, v == 0]}, \[Gamma], {u, 0, 1/2}, {v, 0, 1/2}]
```

I get instead the warning

```
 `There are more dependent variables than equations, so the system is underdetermined`
```

Answer (score 2):

When you look at the message:

[image]

You will see a blue circle-i at the end. Click on that, it will take you to the message ref page for this issue, and that page explains the cause of this and how to avoid it.

For reference: see [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/ref/message/InitializePDECoefficients/femnlmdor.html?view=all) and [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/FEMDocumentation/tutorial/FiniteElementBestPractice.html#645342754).

What you need to do: Write down your equation, then write down the coefficient form of the FEM equation referred to in the message ref page and the finite element best practice tutorial. You need to match your equation to the FEM coefficient form. If you have problems with that you could add the information to your question.

Here is how that procedure would work in principal. We start from an Expand-ed form of your equation:

```
yourOp = 
  Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, 
     v]*(6*Cot[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]^2 - 
      2*Derivative[0, 2][\[Gamma]][u, v] + 
      3*Cos[\[Gamma][u, v]]*
       Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]) - (Derivative[0, 
        1][\[Gamma]][u, 
      v]*(2*(2 + Cos[2*\[Gamma][u, v]])*Csc[\[Gamma][u, v]]*
        Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]^2 + 
       3*Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v] - 
       2*Cos[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[2, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]));


Expand[yourOp] // InputForm

yourOpExpanded = 
  6*Cot[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]^2*
    Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v] - 
   2*Derivative[0, 2][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
    Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v] - 
   4*Csc[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
    Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]^2 - 
   2*Cos[2*\[Gamma][u, v]]*Csc[\[Gamma][u, v]]*
    Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
    Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]^2 - 
   3*Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
    Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v] + 
   3*Cos[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
    Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v] + 
   2*Cos[\[Gamma][u, v]]*Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
    Derivative[2, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v];
```

Now, we start by looking at one term:

```
yourOpExpanded =(*6*Cot[\[Gamma][u,v]]*Derivative[0,1][\[Gamma]][u,
  v]^2*Derivative[1,0][\[Gamma]][u,
  v]*)-2*Derivative[0, 2][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
   Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, 
    v](*-4*Csc[\[Gamma][u,v]]*Derivative[0,1][\[Gamma]][u,v]*\
Derivative[1,0][\[Gamma]][u,v]^2-2*Cos[2*\[Gamma][u,v]]*Csc[\[Gamma][\
u,v]]*Derivative[0,1][\[Gamma]][u,v]*Derivative[1,0][\[Gamma]][u,v]^2-\
3*Derivative[0,1][\[Gamma]][u,v]*Derivative[1,1][\[Gamma]][u,v]+3*Cos[\
\[Gamma][u,v]]*Derivative[1,0][\[Gamma]][u,v]*Derivative[1,1][\[Gamma]\
][u,v]+2*Cos[\[Gamma][u,v]]*Derivative[0,1][\[Gamma]][u,v]*Derivative[\
2,0][\[Gamma]][u,v]*);

yourOpExpanded // InputForm
-2*Derivative[0, 2][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
 Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]
```

Next, we set of an Inactive Div/Grad term:

```
inactiveOp = 
 Inactive[
   Div][-{{0 , 0}, {0, 2*Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]}} . 
    Inactive[Grad][\[Gamma][u, v], {u, v}], {u, v}]
```

And we compare to your form:

```
(Activate[inactiveOp] - yourOpExpanded) // InputForm
-2*Derivative[0, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]*
 Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]
```

Because we pulled the term `-2*Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]` into the inactive Div/Grad term we need to compensate that:

```
inactiveOp = 
 Inactive[
    Div][-{{0 , 0}, {0, 2*Derivative[1, 0][\[Gamma]][u, v]}} . 
     Inactive[Grad][\[Gamma][u, v], {u, v}], {u, v}] + {0, 
    2*Derivative[1, 1][\[Gamma]][u, v]} . 
   Inactive[Grad][\[Gamma][u, v], {u, v}]

Activate[inactiveOp] - yourOpExpanded
0
```

You need to do this for all terms. Also, note that when adding a new term sometimes it may be better to re-write a previous addition. Because we do not know where your equation comes from it's hard to say how to approach this. But also note that the Inactive form of the PDE is, very, very general. Good luck!